# JavaScript: Is it possible to edit existing key names?

Tags: javascript, object

Using JavaScript, is it possible to change an existing key name in an object, other than by removing the entire key-value pair and adding a new one in its place?

The sort of thing about which I am asking would, if possible, look generally like this:

```
myObj = {'a':1, 'b':2,}; 

Object.keys(myObj)[i] = 'newKeyName';
```

...except that instead of editing an array made by extracting the key names, one would actually edit the key name itself in the source object.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, that's the best way to do it.

```
var a = { b: 'c', d: 'e' };

a.f = a.b;
delete a.b;

console.log(a);  // { d: 'e', f: 'c' }
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. I was thinking I might just be failing to remember the proper assignment statement, but as you confirmed, no, you just can't do that in a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with some perf.

```
obj = {'a':1,'b':2}
oldKey = 'a'
newKey = 'x'

if (oldKey !== newKey) {
    Object.defineProperty(obj, newKey,
        Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, oldKey));
    delete obj[oldKey];
}
```